# How to set up toolchain to compile for beaglebone on OS X?

Tags: macos, cross-compiling, beagleboard

I want to be able to cross-compile C code on my MacBook targeting the ARM7a on my new beaglebone.  There are a lot of examples of how to do this in linux, but they all require packages that haven't been necessarily set up on OS X yet.

So, I'd like to put a toolchain together...  If I can figure it out, then I'll post how it was done.

What I don't know is exactly what packages I need to compile & install.  I'm sure I need a binutils for the arm, which fink seems to be able to install...  I have Xcode & the command line tools, so there's gcc.

Anyone know what else do I need to put together to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need the same packages you would for Linux, but sometimes it seems like you need to do extra work. I would recommend using macports as it's good for setting up dependencies, and reviewing what is being done in the Linux examples.